# I am trying to fit an CuDNNLSTM model and I am getting an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am learning about recurrent neural networks and I found out CuDNNLSTM layer, which is much faster than usual LSTM. So, I have tried to fit a CuDNNLSTM model, but the only thing, which program display is "Epoch 1" and then nothing is happening and my kernel is dying (I am working in jupyter-notebook). In jupyer terminal I have find this:

> 2022-05-25 22:22:59.693801: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:384] Loaded cuDNN version 8100
>
> 2022-05-25 22:23:00.149065: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1018] failed to
> synchronize the stop event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified
> launch failure
>
> 2022-05-25 22:23:00.149218: E
> tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/gpu_timer.cc:55] INTERNAL: Error
> destroying CUDA event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch
> failure
>
> 2022-05-25 22:23:00.150008: E
> tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/gpu_timer.cc:60] INTERNAL: Error
> destroying CUDA event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch
> failure
>
> 2022-05-25 22:23:00.150355: F
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:217] Check failed:
> status== CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (7 vs. 0)Failed to set cuDNN stream.

I have installed tensorflow-gpu and compatible CuDNN and CUDA to my tensorflow version

tensorflow version: 2.9.0

CUDA version: 11.2

CuDNN version: 8.1

I have tried also same model, but with LSTM layers and that have worked, but still it is very slow, so I want to figure out how to use a CuDNNLSTM model.

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.layers import CuDNNLSTM

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train/255.0
X_test = X_test/255.0

model = Sequential()

model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
      
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
      
model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
      
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
      
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3, decay=1e-5)
      
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=["accuracy"])
      
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

If somebody had same problem or know how to fix that, I will be grateful for help.
Thanks in an advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this with the `tanh` activation function?  From my understanding, it has to use that.  Details below:

> Long Short-Term Memory layer - Hochreiter 1997.
> See [the Keras RNN API guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn)
> for details about the usage of RNN API.
> Based on available runtime hardware and constraints, this layer
> will choose different implementations (cuDNN-based or pure-TensorFlow)
> to maximize the performance. If a GPU is available and all
> the arguments to the layer meet the requirement of the cuDNN kernel
> (see below for details), the layer will use a fast cuDNN implementation.
> The requirements to use the cuDNN implementation are:
>
> 1. `activation` == `tanh`
> 2. `recurrent_activation` == `sigmoid`
> 3. `recurrent_dropout` == 0
> 4. `unroll` is `False`
> 5. `use_bias` is `True`
> 6. Inputs, if use masking, are strictly right-padded.
> 7. Eager execution is enabled in the outermost context.

Comment: I have read that guide, and I have replaced "CuDNNLSTM" layers with normal LSTM layers and I add to them "tanh" activation function. Now it`s working and seems to use GPU and everything is right: 

Epoch 3/3
1875/1875 [==============================] - 16s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0801 - accuracy: 0.9780 - val_loss: 0.0662 - val_accuracy: 0.9818

Thanks a lot! I was trying to figure out that since yesterday! I am just watching old tutorials with old tensorflow and there were a bit diffrent implementation of CuDNN model fitting. Thanks a lot one more time!

Comment: You're welcome! Isn't it nice when things work out?  Best of luck!